# symfony 3 - project in git - how to install on other machine?

Tags: php, git, symfony, installation

I'm new to Symfony but like it a lot. I'm on a Mac.
I have a project (installed via "symfony new project_name".
It runs on my machine using "php bin/console server:run".
I have checked it in into my own git repository.
On another Mac I want to install this same project for my colleague.

We tried this:
Install new project with the same name on his computer and after that check out the git repository in that folder.
It does not work! :(

I have googled a lot, but couldn't find anything for this case.
Is there any instruction out there or can anyone explain the right way to me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Clone the git repository. Run `composer install`, run `php bin/console server:run`, assuming (s)he has php and a db installed.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Only thing is, the composer.json, composer.lock and README.md should not be checked in. We had copied them locally because there are paths with our names in it...

Comment: Yes they should definitely be checked in

Answer (score 0):

Check that he has the same version of Symfony installed (globally or in that directory) as you do, and check if he has [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) installed especially if you have dependencies installed.

My colleagues and I have run into similar issues and eventually we worked around it using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) which runs a linux container that holds your code and whatever other resources you have for the project. Then when you push/pull your code it lives in one spot (the container) instead of two individual computers.  A quick Google on Docker should get you started.

This route takes some setup, but it is great afterwards,
good luck!